# Show tasks in Google Calendar app

Tags: google-calendar, google-tasks

There is a "Tasks" calendar that can be selected on the Google Calendar web interface, that displays all Gmail tasks deadlines. This calendar is not shown/synced in the Google Calendar app. Is there a adapter app that works for tasks like maybe the Birthday Adapter app works for events? I'm not looking for a separate tasks app unless it can also hook into Google Calendar to show my tasks there.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Reminders](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285327), the successor of Google Tasks. You can switch back and forth between Tasks and Reminders by opening the [web interface](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/render), clicking the arrow next to 'Tasks' in the sidebar and selecting 'Switch to Reminders' from the menu.

Comment: I was using Reminders but switched to Tasks after an answer to my question https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/134945/how-to-mark-google-calendar-reminder-as-done-with-a-prior-date suggested it. Then I discovered this problem. Such a pain; I wish Google would integrate Tasks and Reminders taking the best features of each.